# How to pass const/non-const member function to BOOST_TYPEOF?

Tags: c++, boost, constants, c++03, typeof

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
struct Test
{
    const int& foo();
   // const int& foo() const;
};

int main()
{
    BOOST_TYPEOF(&Test::foo) ss;
}
```

This code compiles. After uncommening the second function I am getting error because it doesn't know which function `foo` is given. How is it possible to pass const or nonconst member function here?

The problem is from here:

```
template<typename Class, typename T>
struct MemberFuctionHasConstRefReturnType
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename Class, typename T>
struct MemberFuctionHasConstRefReturnType<Class, const T&(Class::*)()const>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

This metafunction checks if return type of a member function is const reference. I cant pass const/ non-const function to it.

Comment: It's not the *constness* of the overloaded function that is the problem, if you added an overload taking an argument (for example) you would get the same error. The problem is that the compiler really doesn't know which function you mean when you say `&Test::foo`.

Comment: Why do you need both?  Just use const int & foo() const;

Comment: Ok, but can we pass for example const version?

Comment: What're you actually going to do with `ss`?

Comment: This is for unit testing. I am trying to write metafunction to check return type of member function. All is working except for 2 functions with same name const / non const

Comment: @Ashot Do you know the arguments?

Comment: Yes, it has no arguments

Comment: @Ashot `decltype(declval<Test>().foo())` and `decltype(declval<const Test>().foo())>()` do it with a c++11 compliant compiler - since I see `BOOST_TYPEOF`, I assume you are using an older compiler? C++03 compliant?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `decltype`. I am using c++03 compiler. It is quite easy to do this in c++11.

Comment: There are two methods. You must specify which one. To specify which one, you need to know the types. There's no way around it. @Ashot, when there are two `::foo` methods, you need to tell us (and the compiler) which one you want. To do that, you probably need to stop using BOOST_TYPEOF and actually specify the type.

Comment: (Another comment where I'll try to be more helpful!) @Ashot, it's possible to specify that the two methods have a different return type. The `const` could return `string`, while the non-const returns `int`. Therefore, it is not meaningful to ask "what is the return type of `foo`"? The number of parameters could change also. This is why it is important to specify whether you want the `const` or non-const version.

Comment: Anyhow, the way to disambiguate the overload in C++03 is `static_cast<const int &(Test::*)() const>(&Test::foo)` (or without the const, depending on which overload you want to pick). But I guess it's not useful for you...